# How to connect to docker redis cluster from local host

Tags: java, docker, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I created redis docker cluster using the script:

**Cluster_creation.sh**

```
#------------ bootstrap the cluster nodes --------------------

start_cmd='redis-server --port 6379 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes'
redis_image='redis:5.0-rc'
network_name='docker-it-network'

docker network create $network_name
echo $network_name " created"

#---------- create the cluster ------------------------

for port in `seq 6379 6384`; do \
 docker run -d --name "redis-"$port -p $port:6379 --net $network_name $redis_image $start_cmd;
 echo "created redis cluster node redis-"$port
done

cluster_hosts=''

for port in `seq 6379 6384`; do \
 hostip=`docker inspect -f '{{(index .NetworkSettings.Networks "docker-it-network").IPAddress}}' "redis-"$port`;
 echo "IP for cluster node redis-"$port "is" $hostip
 cluster_hosts="$cluster_hosts$hostip:6379 ";
done

echo "cluster hosts "$cluster_hosts
echo "creating cluster...."
echo 'yes' | docker run -i --rm --net $network_name $redis_image redis-cli --cluster create $cluster_hosts --cluster-replicas 1;
```

this script created the cluster and all the nodes are connected.

[image]

However i am not able to connect to this redis cluster through my spring boot application.
I tried using localhost:6379 ,  127.0.0.1:6379, host.docker.internal:6379 but none of this worked.

How do I expose the redis cluster docker container to be consumed by the application in local?

Note: application isn't running in docker. If application is running in docker, I can access redis with redis endpoint as **redis-6379:6379**.  However can't access directly from the local host machine using localhost:6379

ERROR:

```
gframework.data.redis.TooManyClusterRedirectionsException: No more cluster attempts left.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterMaxAttemptsException: No more cluster attempts left.
```

docker inspect docker-it-network:

```
{
        "Name": "docker-it-network",
        "Id": "46fc0aacb845bb6fddf36ba85f57f346414594730299cc28ff85a70e3bff1227",
        "Created": "2021-08-06T14:37:59.189023848Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
           
            "1105aea5de2ccaa4bdbd01b849c7ff0447299f407112e586ec3943596d2df2ef": {
                "Name": "redis-6382",
                "EndpointID": "a3f81288c528d37033ec3f091d00a879022558e58614fe9e73626dcaa136d68e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "233e19cbad6658a65593fcfc8d50688b9b88e7edc1d5f0b8d959ba640c9a3e74": {
                "Name": "redis-6383",
                "EndpointID": "e0703f96fd6efaef6a7ebf1af6e22151ae85418f62a501fb042ed58d5a364250",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3372eaf8ceb5b8024202f5bf0421b5ccc697ca6ccbcded5238b1ac05ef1d81bb": {
                "Name": "redis-6381",
                "EndpointID": "34e11bb16cd3c41aed6d75b35443d043ab7fedd5719b63c3be1d311fb6bfc9d0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "45c0ac3378e4c85dfe766e030779c94c39028253744c734ba483154a0fe0d722": {
                "Name": "redis-6384",
                "EndpointID": "10e43a763b66727ce4f4fc4a90a6a057768772d2c97596454bf2ec4134cc18f7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
          
            "8e757a3c2dbb95f9b330fa7ea0bad6c0cf4485fbeeaae92be2e596bccc02b309": {
                "Name": "redis-6379",
                "EndpointID": "a4a236ca36f4704667c4634564c7b42e5b8d8c308e381efadb408fe11dfb221c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
           
            "fdeace5cff0a5d8ccb5875863f97033426ce97e07224b5ec24b918a017b1701e": {
                "Name": "redis-6380",
                "EndpointID": "87c837fdcca1f2c8f7c23f369f61b2aa17014a63d21c10823563a6874526d76d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Where is the application actually running -- in a container or not, on the same host or not?  (All of these contexts will believe they are themselves `localhost` so "in local" isn't a great description.)  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze application isn't running in container.

Comment: What is the output if you execute this command `docker inspect docker-it-network` (maybe the scope or the driver is wrong and block your local traffic to the redis containers).

Comment: @EnriqueTejedaRodriguez updated the output of network inspect

Comment: Please see this thread may be can be helpful for your case (the problem is locate in the redis config and not in the docker networking)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162024/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-redis-cluster-instance-using-jedis-for-java

Comment: @EnriqueTejeda what should be the value of cluster-announce-ip?

Comment: @Programmer Were you able to resolve this? How?